# How to merge single command for multiple options using getopt python

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to merge more than two command line options using python getopt module

```
import optparse
parser = optparse.OptionParser(prog='Running the commmand')

parser.add_option('-b','--basic', action="store_true",help='help file')
parser.add_option('-c', '--catch',action="store_true",help='help file')
opts, args = parser.parse_args( )

#print options.outputs

if opts.basic:
   print "basic"
```

for this file if I run with **A.py -b** How to execute b and c related code.

Comment: Why do you need to execute `-b` and `-c` related code? If you execute `-c` code anyway then why adding this argument in the first place?

Comment: thanks for your reply
Some time we need result in Basic and as well as Catch information in single output/console.

Answer (score 0):

> for this file if I run with A.py -b How to execute b and c related code.

The answer is **no**: because this is 2 different options.
if you run with `A.py -b` you will see the word `basic` in output
if you run with `A.py -c` you will not see anything in output.

> To execute this code with b and c run
>   A.py -b -c

You can add the following code to the end of your file to check it.:

```
if opts.catch:
  print "catch"
```

Example:

```
python A.py  -c
catch
python A.py  -b
basic
python A.py  -b -c
basic
catch
```